# IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for Google Maps

Tags: ios, uiview, uistoryboard, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using GoogleMaps Pod in my project. I have error in one of my Storyboard:

> error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for MapViewController: dlopen(GoogleMaps.framework, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       GoogleMaps.framework: mach-o, but wrong filetype

I have set view class to GMSMapView:

[image]

App is working on simulator. How I can fix this error? It causes whole storyboard to be blank.

Comment: storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for NearByPlaceListingViewController (yxD-BC-CKt): dlopen(GoogleMaps.framework, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find: GoogleMaps.framework: mach-o, but wrong filetype                     I am getting Same Error... in Xcode 9.2

Comment: Please suggest if you have fixed.

Comment: I’m creating this map view form code right now, I couldn’t make it work from storyboard. @ShahabuddinVansiwala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GMSMapView manually by writing code in simulator; Instead of using `GMSMapView` in storyboard.

If you are using maps in multiple screen. then write code manually for all file.

```
@IBOutlet weak var map_Views: UIView!
var map_View = GMSMapView()
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: Double(main_latitude)!, longitude: Double(main_longitude)!, zoom: 6.0)
     map_View = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    map_Views = map_View

    map_View.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:Double(main_latitude)!,
                                                    longitude:Double(main_longitude)!,
                                                    zoom:10.0,
                                                    bearing: 0,
                                                    viewingAngle: 0)

}
```

Comment: I made this that way, and posted it here, my answer had 3 downvotes. :/

Comment: @Prettygeek Please share link of your answer

Comment: I deleted it like 4 months ago.

Answer (score 5):

Create Subclass of GMSMapView and use that class name instead of GMSMapView. after adding this error will not occur and whole storyboard is working.

```
import GoogleMaps

class GoogleMapView : GMSMapView {

}
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem in my case. I even changed GMSMapView to simple UIView and I still have storyboard issues, despite cleaning, deleting derived data and restarting Xcode.